# How can I Identify, what data available in Bufferpools and to which transaction that data is related?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

Currently could see my DB2 10.5 is using 40 GB of available memory and all this memory was getting used by bufferpool of size 4K. can you please help in ways for identifying below requirement

1. way to identify Hot Data available memory and
2. to which transaction data available in memory and how much size of
   memory that transaction used for processing query.
3. how frequent that data is getting accessed
4. what transaction query is using more memory.

Comment: While it might be possible to collect the information you want, you probably need to first articulate _why_ you want it. What is it specifically that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I wanna know which one of my tables are in the bufferpool and which one of them used the most memory resource

Comment: You're just rephrasing your original question; instead, explain _why_ you "wanna know which one of my tables are in the bufferpool".

Comment: I want to tune that table and somehow optimise it in order to improve the performance

Comment: Tables don't have "performance" and you can "tune" them. You need to identify SQL statements that don't perform according to your requirements and tune those.

Answer (score 0):

1. *way to identify Hot Data available memory*

> db2pd -db *mydb*
>   [-pages](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0011729.html?view=kc#r0011729__pdpages)
>   summary

The command above prints the following table with summary for all bufferpools & object pages in them.

```
Summary info for all bufferpools:                                                                                                                      
BPID TbspaceID  ObjID      Total      Dirty      Permanent  Temporary  Data       Index      LongField  XMLData    SMP        LOB        LOBA       BMP
```

You may decode tables and indexes from this output using the following select statements:

```
-- Data pages
SELECT TABSCHEMA, TABNAME, PARTITIONOBJECTID
FROM SYSCAT.DATAPARTITIONS
WHERE TBSPACEID = <TbspaceID> AND PARTITIONOBJECTID = <ObjID>;

-- Index pages
SELECT I.TABSCHEMA, I.TABNAME, I.INDNAME
FROM SYSCAT.INDEXES I
JOIN SYSCAT.TABLES T ON T.TABSCHEMA = I.TABSCHEMA AND T.TABNAME = I.TABNAME
LEFT JOIN SYSCAT.INDEXPARTITIONS P ON P.INDSCHEMA = I.INDSCHEMA AND P.INDNAME = I.INDNAME
WHERE 
    COALESCE(P.INDPARTITIONTBSPACEID, I.TBSPACEID)     = <TbspaceID> 
AND COALESCE(P.INDPARTITIONOBJECTID, I.INDEX_OBJECTID) = <ObjID>;
```

You may think, that all these pages are "hot".

2. *to which transaction data available in memory and how much size of memory that transaction used for processing query*

All transactions may use the same pages in bufferpools, and there is no information on what transaction touched some particular page in memory.
What you may get from transaction is metrics for:

- [uow logical data group](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.mon.doc/doc/r0007595.html?view=kc#r0007595__UowLogicalDataGroup) and [uow_metrics logical data group](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.mon.doc/doc/r0007595.html?view=kc#r0007595__UowmetricsLogicalDataGroup), if you use [Unit of work event monitoring](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.mon.doc/doc/c0055273.html)
- [MON_GET_UNIT_OF_WORK table function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0053939.html), if you want to get information on currently running transactions

You may look at the `POOL_x_READS` / `POOL_x_WRITES` / `POOL_x_REQ` metrics to understand how much data was touched in bufferpools and `x_SORT_x` metrics to understand sort memory use by the transaction.

3. *how frequent that data is getting accessed*

We don't have such an information on pages in bufferpools.

4. *what transaction query is using more memory*

The same as for transactions (or unit of works), you may have the following statistics for queries:

- [pkgcache logical data group](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.mon.doc/doc/r0007595.html?view=kc#r0007595__PkgcacheLogicalDataGroup) and [pkgcache_metrics logical data group](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.mon.doc/doc/r0007595.html?view=kc#r0007595__PkgcachemetricsLogicalDataGroup), if you use [Package cache statement eviction event monitoring](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.mon.doc/doc/c0056443.html)
- [MON_GET_PKG_CACHE_STMT table function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0055017.html), if you want to get current package cache contents in the database